# Symfony: Load resources into the Translator from within a Service

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a Symfony (2.7.4) website where some users have their own language resources for their own locales. For example, a user might have two locales (for example `fr` and `en`) and another user could also have one or all of these locales.

Each user has the ability to edit its own translations in a third party app, so translations are not shared between users.

I would like to be able to load the appropriate (YML or XLIFF) resources file when accessing a user's page, based on the locale (which is defined in the URL) and the user (could be its ID or anything that identifies it).

For example, when visiting `user99.my-domain.ext/fr/` I'd like to add `[base_directory]/user99/messages.fr.yml` to the resources loaded by the Translator so it overrides the keys in the base `messages.fr.yml`.

I've tried to inject the Translator in my service, but I can only use it for reading translations, not adding any. What would be the best way to do that? Or is doing it in a service is too late? Maybe the Kernel is a better place?

Any help is appreciated!

Note: I'm using the YAML format in my examples, but any of the Symfony-known formats is eligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to use a custom Twig filter, so I can decide when I want user specific translations and when I want generic ones.

Here's my extension (my users are in fact `Domain` instances):

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Twig/DomainTranslationExtension

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use AppBundle\Document\Domain;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;

class DomainTranslationExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    protected $container;

    /**
     * @var Translator
     */
    protected $translator;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $locale;

    /**
     * @var Domain
     */
    protected $domain;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->locale = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest()->getLocale();

        $domainService = $this->container->get('app.domain_service');
        $this->domain = $domainService->getDomain();

        // TODO: File loading error check
        $this->translator = new Translator($this->locale);
        $this->translator->addLoader('yaml', new YamlFileLoader());
        $this->translator->addResource('yaml', 'path/to/domain-translations/' . $this->domain->getSlug() . '/messages.' . $this->locale . '.yml', $this->locale);
    }

    public function getFilters() {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('transDomain', array($this, 'transDomain')),
        );
    }

    public function transDomain($s) {
        $trans = $this->translator->trans($s);
        // Falling back to default translation if custom isn't available
        if ($trans == $s) {
            $trans = $this->container->get('translator')->trans($s);
        }
        return $trans;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'app_translation_extension';
    }

}
```

Declared like that in `app/config/services.yml`:

```
app.domain_service:
    class: AppBundle\Services\DomainService
    arguments: [ @request_stack, @doctrine_mongodb, @translation.loader ]
```

And used like that in a Twig file:

```
{{ 'my.translation.key'|transDomain }}
```

I hope this helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to "override" translations you should decorate the `translator` service. That way your own translator logic will be executed when `trans()` is called somewhere.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#decorating-services

By decorating the service other bundles will also start using the logic you did describe above. You can inject the active user (eg. `token_storage` service) and some caching services (eg. https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCacheBundle) to make sure your user gets the right translations.

This isn't related to the request or hostname, your translation logic for the user should happen after the firewall / authorization logic was executed.

See Symfony's `LoggingTranslator` PR to find out how the decorator pattern was used to let the translator log missing translations: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/10887/files

Comment: Looks like what I'm looking for, yep! I will also try to see if writing my own `|transUser` Twig filter could help... I'll let you know what was the best option.